# I need to copy all files not older 3 days from folder c:/t/ to folder c:/t/1 how do i make?

Tags: powershell

How do I copy files from one folder `c:\t` to other folder `c:\t\1` based on date (files not older than three days will be copied)?
How do I modify this code to enter sourse folders?

```
ls -File | ?{
    $_.CreationTime -ge $(Get-Date).AddDays(-3) -and
    $_.LastWriteTime -ge $(Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
} | Copy-Item -destination C:\ps\1
```

Comment: comparing date _strings_ is iffy. you are usually better off to compare the date _objects_. [*grin*] for instance, your `$Date in line 2 is a datetime object & so is the `$File.CreationTime` - so those will compare AS IS.

Comment: You probably want to compare the last modification time rather than the creation time. Your reference date is 1 day ago, not 3 days ago. Also, you check if the date of the file is the same as the reference date (`-eq`) when you're looking for files that are newer (`-gt`).

Answer (score 1):

this uses a slightly different approach. since folks often get date math reversed, this does the comparison on `days old` instead of directly comparing the date objects.

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$DestDir = 'D:\Temp'
# this gives you the date with the time set to midnite
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$MinDaysOld = 3

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $DaysOld = ($Today - $FL_Item.CreationTime.Date).Days

    if ($DaysOld -gt $MinDaysOld)
        {
        'the file below is {0} days old.' -f $DaysOld
        # remove the "-WhatIf" when you are ready to do it for real
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName -Destination $DestDir -WhatIf
        ''
        }
    }
```

truncated output ...

```
the file below is 21 days old.
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\user2310119_append-csv-to-TXT-file.txt Desti
nation: D:\Temp\user2310119_append-csv-to-TXT-file.txt".

the file below is 49 days old.
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1559095937.log Destinati
on: D:\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1559095937.log".

[*...snip...*] 

the file below is 34 days old.
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1560382575.log Destinati
on: D:\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1560382575.log".

the file below is 7 days old.
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1562704735.log Destinati
on: D:\Temp\vscode-inno-updater-1562704735.log".
```

Comment: why does this example do not work? ls -file|?{$_.CreationTime -ge $(get-date).AddDays(-3) -and $_.LastWriteTime -ge $(get-date).AddDays(-3)}| Copy-Item -destination C:\t\1

Comment: @daver - you are asking for files that are NEWER than 3 days ago AND you are not setting the source location. so ... are there any files that are newer than 3  days ago AND in whatever location your code thot was current? [*grin*] ///// if i set the source dir to my `c:\temp` & the dest dir to `d:\temp`, your code will copy the 4 files that are less that 3 days old to the destination on my system.

Comment: @daver - um, er, what is the point of posting my answer code in a reply to my question about the code in your reply to me post?

Comment: @daver - so, the comment has changed ... [*grin*] ///// you have spaces in your path names. for instance >>> `c: \ 1.ps1` has a space before the `\` and another after it. those are not valid paths. ///// my code was not designed to run as a parameterized script ... you did NOT mention that requirement.

Comment: how to make progress during file copy? we need to know in code what files were copied and some files were old and were not copied

Comment: @daver - that is a new problem ... please make a new question with your current code and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get a list of files that are less than 3 days old then just get the child items and pass it into a `Where-Object`:

```
$now = [DateTime]::Now
$files = Get-ChildItem -File *.* | ? {$now.Subtract($_.CreationTime).TotalDays -lt 3}
```

(Note: `?` is an alias for `Where-Object`)

`$files` now contains all the files less than 3 days old.

You can now copy the files by passing the `$files` list into the `ForEach-Object` command:

```
$files | % {Copy-Item $_ -Destination c:\t\1}
```

(Note: `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`)

Putting this all together you get:

```
$now = [DateTime]::Now
$files = Get-ChildItem -File c:\t\*.* | ? {$now.Subtract($_.CreationTime).TotalDays -lt 3}
$files | % {Copy-Item $_ -Destination c:\t\1}
```

Or you can combine it like this, using piping:

```
$now = [DateTime]::Now
Get-ChildItem -File c:\t\*.* | ? {$now.Subtract($_.CreationTime).TotalDays -lt 3} | % {Copy-Item $_ -Destination c:\t\1}
```

Comment: @daver - PLEASE make up your mind. your question title says `files older than three days` and now you are saying the reverse ... what is the actual thing you want?

Comment: @daver - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6

Comment: @daver - just supply the source as a variable instead of a literal string.

Comment: @daver - If you want to look in subdirectories then use the `-Recurse` flag when calling `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: @daver - `Get-ChildItem` let's you specify multiple locations as a list: `Get-ChildItem -File c:\t*.*,c:\f*.*,c:\u*.*,c:\s*.*`

Comment: last example copy all files but not only 3 days old

Comment: $now = [DateTime]::Now
Get-ChildItem -File c:\t\*.*,c:\f\*.*,c:\u\*.*,c:\s\*.* | ? {$now.Subtract($_.CreationTime).TotalDays -lt 3} | % {Copy-Item $_ -Destination c:\t\1}

Comment: why does last code copy all files and not only 3 days old?